# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This paragraph is not the first one in the table

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read table data from doc file using apache poi in java while executing I am getting this error I am unable to found for what reason this error is coming.

```
fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
            HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fs);

            Range range = document.getRange();

            for(int i=0;i<range.numParagraphs();i++) {
                Paragraph paragraph = range.getParagraph(i);
                System.out.println("Paragraph :"+(i+1));
                System.out.println("is in Table :"+paragraph.isInTable());
                if(paragraph.isInTable()) {
                    Table table =range.getTable(paragraph);
                    for(int rowIndex=0;rowIndex<table.numRows();rowIndex++) {
                        TableRow tableRow = table.getRow(rowIndex);
                        System.out.println("Row :"+(rowIndex+1)+", is table header :"+tableRow.isTableHeader());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("is Table row end :"+paragraph.isTableRowEnd());
                System.out.println(paragraph.text().replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "").replaceAll("[:-]", "").trim());
            }
```

Can someone please help to resolve this error.

`Table table =range.getTable(paragraph);`

In this line it is showing

Comment: Cloud please edit the question and add the stacktrace to see the line taht triggers it

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply I add the line in which it is showing could you please tell me where I am doing mistake.

Comment: Thanks Kumar but if i have the whole stacktrace it would be great! thank you

Comment: The exception is quite clear, you do not have a table starting at the paragraph you give to the getTable method. Can you provide the document you try to read ? Also, your table can contain several paragraphs, I don't think you have one table by paragraph ?